# Vue.js How to toggle individual v-if divs inside a v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'd like to show/hide a dropdown menu for each of the posts in a `v-for` loop which is clicked:

```
<div v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="index" >
    <div v-on:click.prevent="toggleDropDown(post)">Show/hide menu
    </div>
   <div  v-if="post.showDropDown"> 
      <ul class="menu">         
          <li><a href="#" >Edit</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >Delete</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
         {{post.body}}

    </div> 
</div>
```

And the method:

```
toggleDropDown(post) {
   if (!post.showDropDown) {     
      post.showDropDown =true;   
   } else {       
      post.showDropDown =false;  
   }
  },
```

But it does not work. Nothing happens when I click `Show/hide menu`

Note that `posts` are fetched from server and `post` object has no `showDropDown` field.

Instead of `v-if="post.showDropDown"` I could simply use `"showDropDown=!showDropDown"` but then all the menus on all posts open/close together, which is not intended.

How can I fix it?

Comment: 'Note that posts are fetched from server and post object has no showDropDown field.' Well, a showDropDown attribute is kind of essential in your code.  Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vapk2Lh5/ . In other words, you can fix it by adding a showDropDown attribute to your post object.

Comment: Well, that's an unnecessary overhead imho. There should be a way around it.

Comment: Rephrase your question in that case. Now your basically asking: 'How can I fix not declaring my attribute?'  and saying that declaring attributes before using them is unnecessary overhead, which doesn't make any sense. It's like "Hi my car won't move", -"Sir your car is missing wheels", 'Well that's just an unnecessary overhead".

Comment: Please add more to your sample code as it's not giving a clear picture, and as stated above, rephrase if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be Vue reactivity problem. You can try using `Vue.set`

Change your html code to pass `index` instead of `post`

```
<div v-on:click.prevent="toggleDropDown(index)">Show/hide menu
</div>
```

then in javascript

```
toggleDropDown(index) {
 if (!this.posts[index].showDropDown) {
    this.$set(this.posts[index], 'showDropDown', true)
 } else {       
    this.$set(this.posts[index], 'showDropDown', false)  
 }
}
```

If it doesn't work, you can try making deep copy with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`

```
toggleDropDown(index) {
  this.posts[index].showDropDown = !this.posts[index].showDropDown
  this.posts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.posts))
}
```

Comment: it could be simplified to this if post object is passed: `toggleDropDown(post) { this.$set(post, 'showDropDown', !post.showDropDown) }`

Comment: @MaxSinev your solution works fine and it's elegant. Thanks!